# integrated Tomcat with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am working on integrate Tomcat version 7.0.104 with Eclipse, my JDK is jdk-11.0.7
I already config servers in Eclipse . But when I try to start it, it's showing those error, my Tomcat working fine when started with /bin/startup.bat, how to solve this issue?
thanks a lot!
[image: Could not create java Virtual Machine]

[image: failed to start Tomcat]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this? If not the latest, upgrade--compatibility between newer JDKs and older Tomcat releases wasn't present in older releases.

Answer (score 0):

I just try delete -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.104\endorsed", it works, but don't know why
[image: Edit Launch configuration properties]